# Getting averages by hour/day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query where I'm trying to get the average counts by hour by day. I'm getting the totals without a problem, but I can't seem to get the average.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with the below query, and also how I could get the results in the below format?

```
SELECT 
    [Day], 
    [Hour], 
    [DayN], 
    Totals,
    AVG(Totals) AS [Avg]
FROM
  (
        SELECT 
          [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
          [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
          [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate),
          Totals = COUNT(*)
        from 
            Visit
        where
            StartDate >= '01 Jan 2019'
        GROUP BY 
          DATENAME(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
          DATEPART(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
          DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate)
  ) AS q
GROUP BY [Day], [Hour], Totals, [DayN]
ORDER BY DayN;
```

[image]

Sample Data: (more at https://justpaste.it/65w8z )

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visit](
    [VisitID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL
)

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30513, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:06:28.480' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30514, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:07:23.637' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30515, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:14:44.840' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30516, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:16:05.030' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30517, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:18:23.787' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30518, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:20:33.073' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30519, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:20:42.450' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Visit] ([VisitID], [StartDate]) VALUES (30520, CAST(N'2019-01-01T00:25:03.303' AS DateTime))
GO
```

Comment: You realize your sample data tables are different names. :-)

Comment: How can you get what you are looking for when your sample data is all on 1/1/2019 between midnight and 1am?

Comment: I tried adding more sample data and stack wouldn't allow me to as it said the question had too much code.

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." - anyway around this?

Comment: @Philip create a fiddle on https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Thanks @SalmanA. That site is so difficult to use that I can't even figure out where you copy/paste the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert these rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729250/convert-these-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Try This you need to get avg separately please run this

```
SELECT [Day], [Hour], [DayN], Totals, (
SELECT avg(totals)
FROM
  ( SELECT  [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
            [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
            [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate),
            Totals = COUNT(*)
   FROM Visit
   WHERE StartDate >= '01 Jan 2019'
   GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
            DATEPART(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
            DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate) ) AS qq
WHERE q.[day]=qq.[day]) [Avg]
  FROM
    ( SELECT  [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
              [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
              [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate),
              Totals = COUNT(*)
     FROM Visit
     WHERE StartDate >= '01 Jan 2019'
     GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
              DATEPART(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
              DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate) ) AS q
ORDER BY DayN;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT 
    [Day], 
    [Hour], 
    [DayN], 
    Totals,
    AVG(Totals) AS [Avg],
    A
FROM
  (
        SELECT 
          [Day]  = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
          [DayN] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartDate),
          [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate),
          Totals = COUNT(*),
          COUNT(1)/Count(distinct DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate))  A
        from 
            Visit
        where
            StartDate >= '01 Jan 2019'
        GROUP BY 
          DATENAME(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
          DATEPART(WEEKDAY,StartDate),
          DATEPART(HOUR,StartDate)
  ) AS q
GROUP BY [Day], [Hour], Totals, [DayN],A
ORDER BY DayN;
```

do you need `AVG(Totals) AS [Avg]` anymore? if you don't you can delete 2 last rows

Comment: Thanks @masoud - that gives the same result of the Totals and the AVG though.