# Convert these rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly complicated query, and I'm wondering how I can convert these from rows to columns, so they display in the following format. Average is the column that should be used, total is just there for information but doesn't need to be rolled up.

[image]

snip of a few current results:

[image]

```
SELECT dayofweek                    AS Day, 
       Format(onhour, '00') + ':00' AS Hour, 
       Sum(totals)                  AS Total, 
       Avg(totals)                  AS Average 
FROM   (SELECT Datename(weekday, D.fordate) AS DayOfWeek, 
               H.onhour, 
               Isnull(T.totals, 0)          AS Totals 
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT T.fordate 
                FROM   #visit AS T) AS D 
               CROSS apply (VALUES(0), 
                                  (1), 
                                  (2), 
                                  (3), 
                                  (4), 
                                  (5), 
                                  (6), 
                                  (7), 
                                  (8), 
                                  (9), 
                                  (10), 
                                  (11), 
                                  (12), 
                                  (13), 
                                  (14), 
                                  (15), 
                                  (16), 
                                  (17), 
                                  (18), 
                                  (19), 
                                  (20), 
                                  (21), 
                                  (22), 
                                  (23)) AS H(onhour) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN #visit AS T 
                            ON H.onhour = T.onhour 
                               AND D.fordate = T.fordate) a 
WHERE  onhour NOT IN ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 
                       4, 5, 6, 7, 
                       20, 21, 22, 23 ) 
GROUP  BY dayofweek, 
          onhour 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN dayofweek = 'Monday' THEN 1 
            WHEN dayofweek = 'Tuesday' THEN 2 
            WHEN dayofweek = 'Wednesday' THEN 3 
            WHEN dayofweek = 'Thursday' THEN 4 
            WHEN dayofweek = 'Friday' THEN 5 
            WHEN dayofweek = 'Saturday' THEN 6 
            WHEN dayofweek = 'Sunday' THEN 7 
          END ASC, 
          onhour
```

Comment: How does, for example, 79 become 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Cross tabs query to get your result.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(hh, onhour, 0), 108) + ' - ' 
       + CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(hh, onhour+1, 0), 108) AS Hour, 
       Sum(totals)                  AS Total, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Monday'    THEN totals END) AS Monday  , 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Tuesday'   THEN totals END) AS Tuesday , 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Wednesday' THEN totals END) AS Wednesday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Thursday'  THEN totals END) AS Thursday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Friday'    THEN totals END) AS Friday  , 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Saturday'  THEN totals END) AS Saturday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 'Sunday'    THEN totals END) AS Sunday
FROM   (SELECT Datename(weekday, D.fordate) AS DayOfWeek, 
               H.onhour, 
               Isnull(T.totals, 0)          AS Totals 
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT T.fordate 
                FROM   #visit AS T) AS D 
               CROSS apply (VALUES(0), 
                                  (1), 
                                  (2), 
                                  (3), 
                                  (4), 
                                  (5), 
                                  (6), 
                                  (7), 
                                  (8), 
                                  (9), 
                                  (10), 
                                  (11), 
                                  (12), 
                                  (13), 
                                  (14), 
                                  (15), 
                                  (16), 
                                  (17), 
                                  (18), 
                                  (19), 
                                  (20), 
                                  (21), 
                                  (22), 
                                  (23)) AS H(onhour) 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN #visit AS T 
                            ON H.onhour = T.onhour 
                               AND D.fordate = T.fordate) a 
WHERE  onhour NOT IN ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 
                       4, 5, 6, 7, 
                       20, 21, 22, 23 ) 
GROUP  BY onhour 
ORDER  BY onhour;
```

Comment: Cheers for that

Comment: Is there a good way to get the time column displaying like in the screenshot?

Comment: I have edited to format the hours as desired. This is good because the FORMAT function is very slow.